# phonegap not able to read server on 4G

Tags: servlets, cordova, sencha-touch, 4g

I've currently built a Sencha Touch App(Front end using Sencha CMD) backend is a servlet and I'm using CORS to pass data from backend to front end. When i packaged my app and deployed it on Adobe Phonegap Build it was hitting server on my local wifi ,but when i changed it to 4G the app stopped hitting server. Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting to your server when you are on 4G is that you are no longer in the same network.

When you were on WiFi you could reach your server because you were on the same network.

You would have to make your project accesible from internet. I personally like 
www.openshift.com  (your server is deployed on localhost right?)

Comment: Hi,yes my server is hosted on localhost. How do i make my project accessible from internet.Please advise.

Comment: If you want to access your backend (servlet) you must have a domain accessible from internet, please look at www.openshift.com to see how to achieve this

Comment: Basically you will create a server on their platform (tomcat or jboss) deploy your war into that server and they will give a url to access your application/servlet ... www.redhat.com/myAwesomeApp/myServlet ... then your mobile app should consume data from that url using 4G

Comment: Thanks i had a look at openshift, but it needs a github to upload a war,I'm not sure if my company will alow me to put code in github. Is there any workaround like maybe XAMPP server, will it make localhost accessible from internet?

Comment: You don't need a github account. Just to upload your war through git protocol (git != github). I understand they also support uploading through sftp.Although Openshifht will require some time to get things working. If you want another options besides openshift google "java free hosting"

Comment: Thanks for information, if we use Unix Weblogic or Websphere for hosting tomcat would that work.

Comment: Weblogic, JBoss and Websphere are Java EE containers (.ear) Tomcat is not (only .war)

Comment: Yes but we can deploy Tomcat(.war) file on Webshpere,right?

Comment: yes, WebSphere can do everything Tomcat does and more.

Comment: Thanks , just to confirm once we deploy app on WebSphere the app would read data from server too,right?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I mean currently app is not reading from server since(on 4G) it's on tomcat localhost, but after we deploy the .war file on WebSphere would the front end be able to hit back end (server side) real time?

Comment: is not a matter of what server you are using its a matter of wether or not you are exposing to internet a url to hit the servlet for which you need to either configure your local server to do so (which might be hard) or use a service for hosting your .war .ear or whatever backend you are using. So if it is a java application that usually runs on WebSphere I strongly recommend you to take the time to learn about openshift.This is my last comment on this matter.

Comment: Hi,thanks for suggestion i looked into OpenShift and deployed war file it works fine, however in some areas in my code I'm reading from local file system ( openshift is rejecting that), can you please advise if there's any workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your config.xml has

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Or the address of the server you are trying to hit, and also that the server will respond with a header to allow cross domain requests, e.g.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <origin> | *
```

How the server does that depends on the language used, in php you'd use:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

More info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin